# What is causing my bones to display irregularly?

Tags: modeling, animation, bones, eevee-render-engine, pose-mode

I'm working on a character animation, and on a test render I noticed a part of the model was being displayed incorrectly. I opened a previous version of the file, which contains the same animation, and the same part of the model, with the same exact rotations and coordinates, is being displayed correctly.

In the newer file, I didn't change anything about that animation recently (was working on the environmental aspects before I noticed the bad thumb) so I'm at a loss what could be causing this. I also tried to manually place the bones where they belong, updating the pose library, applying the pose back into the scene and getting the same result. [image]

Comment: Anytime you have render/preview disagreement, check for dependency loops.  Open a console view (main Window menu) and look for dependency cycle warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure...
But this happens to me sometimes (quite often) and I eventually realized that the problem isn't always in pose mode - it lies in bone edit mode

In short
See if they look the same in edit mode
This might not be the problem, but give it a shot.

Comment: Interesting, yeah, I tried looking into Edit mode (in both the broken and correct files), and the coordinates are identical. Everything looks fine! So odd

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so that was weird. I discovered there were two plain axes in the scene. I thought they were just leftovers from some previous tests, so I deleted them, thinking nothing of it. Turns out the thumbs of all things were completely dependent on them in order to look correct. I searched the library but couldn't see how these connections were made (I certainly don't remember adding them there for that purpose)but for now I'll just accept them, hide them, and leave it as is. [image]